# trying to remove everything that matches from the database not just firstordefault

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database

this code works but it only removed the first location in the database. I'm fairly new to .Net framework. I understand I'm using FirstOrDefault; I don't know how to search through the database and remove all instances that match the requirements

```
MMLeagueParticipant removeThisParticipant = db.ParticipatingKids.FirstOrDefault(i=>i.ParticipantId == ParticipantId && i.sport.sport == SportsTab);
if(removeThisParticipant == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("removeThisParticopant in [IActionResults Remove] was null");
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Dashboard");
}
if(removeThisParticipant != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("removeThisParticopant in [IActionResults Remove] was NOT null");
    db.ParticipatingKids.Remove(removeThisParticipant);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");
}
```

**What im trying to do:**

I want to remove all instances in the database where the conditions are met.

**What I tried:**

- .Where()
   `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<LeagueProject.Models.MMLeagueParticipant>' to 'LeagueProject.Models.MMLeagueParticipant'.`
- .All(). but this returns a boolean
- .Contains(). Also returned a boolean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Where` instead of `FirstOrDefault` and `Count()` to check collection

Example:

```
IEnumerable<MMLeagueParticipant> removeThisParticipant = db.ParticipatingKids.Where(i=>i.ParticipantId == ParticipantId && i.sport.sport == SportsTab);
if (removeThisParticipant.Count() != 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("removeThisParticopant in [IActionResults Remove] was NOT null");
     db.ParticipatingKids.RemoveRange(removeThisParticipant);
     db.SaveChanges();
     return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", "Dashboard");   
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("removeThisParticopant in [IActionResults Remove] was null");
    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard","Dashboard");
}
```

Comment: First off the return type of first call will be `IEnumerable<MMLeagueParticipant>`. Second off I'd replace call to `Count()` with call to `Any()` (check `IEnumerable.HasNext` vs actually iterate the collection). Third off you may want to materialize the results with `ToList()`, otherwise the query *may* be run twice.